# How can I use the web service with one or none arguments?

Tags: services

I have a web service with the [Services module](https://drupal.org/project/services) that works perfectly, with an URL like `myweb.com\api\my_conent\124` I obtain the information of `my_content` that has the 124 id.

Now with the URL `myweb.com\api\my_content` I want to obtain all the contents of `my_content`, but it doesn't return anything, a blank page. I have the `'optional' => TRUE,` for the arguments.

How can I use the web service with one or none arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an 'index' operation?
Take a look at the `services.services.api.php` file in services module, docs folder.

In the node resource, you have several different 'operations' ( retrieve, create, update & index, .. ).
Here's the snippet you should look at:

```
$node_resource = array(
    'node' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        ..
        'index' => array(
          'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
          'callback' => '_node_resource_index',
          ..
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $node_resource;
```

GET request to endpoint + resource will trigger 'index'. Read more about it here https://drupal.org/node/783254